# Knockout JS and jQuery UI Dialog's title attribute

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

What is the best way to bind jQuery UI's Dialog title attribute? Initially, on `ko.applyBindings`, KO successfully updates the title attribute. However, after `.dialog()` is called, the bindings are lost.

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jordanarseno/YFBsQ/4/

I *could* just manually observe the textbox for keyup and make the changes to the title using:

```
$("input").live("keyup", function(){
    $("#dialog").dialog( "option", "title", $(this).val());
});
```

But, I'd like to move away from that and follow a more Knockout convention if possible.

What's the best approach here? The question is regarding the title attribute, but it could, in theory, apply to any of Dialog's options...

Comment: Works for me in your fiddle - the title keeps being updated.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the title attribute? I also threw in a `<span>` to show that bindings were working inside the container. The title is right beside the `close` link and persists at `init` regardless of what is typed in... doesn't it? It does for me. In other words, you should see _three_ changes; The textbox itself, the span, and the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been know to use the subscribe function for this.

```
function viewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.title = ko.observable('title');

  self.title.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    $('#dialog').dialog('option', 'title', newValue);
  });
}
```

[jsfiddle it up](http://jsfiddle.net/Zh5Zs/2/)

It's functionally pretty similar to the custom binding method but a lot more straightforward.

Check out the bottom of [this page](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html) for documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You could try with a custom binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.ko_dialog = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) { 
        $(element).dialog({title: ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor())});

    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).dialog("option", "title", ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()));
    }
};
```

And call it in that way:

```
<div id="dialog" data-bind="ko_dialog: textboxinput">
```

I've tried to edit your fiddle but for some reason it didn't work on jsfiddle, but it works on my local pc! Just give it a try... http://jsfiddle.net/YFBsQ/31/

Answer (score 0):

Another Option: Computed - these will be called when a property changes, and ultimately can update your model. The jquery UI works by creating an inner element that has the ID inserted into it's naming schema, thus you needing to target the ID: "#ui-dialog-title-YourIdHere"... Simply, just create a computed property containing the info you need and then within the element, call the jquery insert menthod to the generated UI element via: 
    $("#ui-dialog-title-YourIdHere").html("Updated Title with model vars " + self.var1() + ")");